# remove added new tag in select2 programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I've been using select2 for a custom component and wonder whether there is a method to remove a tag created by a user programmatically. I've tried the following way by getting the data array in select2 and then removing the necessary element and then updating the select2 data attribute.

```
var select2Data = $('.members').select2('data'); //original select2 element data
var select2NewUser = $('.new-tag').data(); //data related to the new tag

$.each(select2Data,function(i){
    if(select2Data[i].id === select2NewUser.id){
        select2Data.splice(i,1);
        return false;
        }
})

$('.members').select2('data',select2Data); //updates the modified data tag

$('.new-tag').remove();
```

This method only update the data object! The view is not updated and the element is still in the select2. How can I remove a tag in select2?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like select2 is not having an option to refresh the list. You can try destroying the select and recreate with updated values. Try

`$('.members').select2("destroy");`

and reinitialize with

`$('.members').select2({data: UpdatedData });`

Comment: well this would remove all the selected data and re init the select2 to the initial state! right?

Comment: Yes but you can have the selected options saved and set it after reinitialization.

Comment: could you let me know how it can be done in your answer?

Comment: i think i have a solution which doesnt require `select2("destroy")`. Please add the relevant HTML also so that i can test it and post it here.